# Is there any api key for google maps api in iphone for testing like in android?

Tags: iphone, ios4, google-maps-api-3

My problem is that I'm disturbed by the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error of google maps web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an API key for web-based mobile applications here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html

The native iOS services do not use an API key.